# react-redux props not rendering data in component

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I almost have my react-redux ecosystem working. But for some reason I can't get my users list rendered. The render() method seems to be called just once, when this.props.users is undefined. However, there are a couple of instances where I can display the store content in console. So I'm not sure why the data is not reaching the view.

main

```
// Store initialization with a test user that should be rendered in view
... 
const store = createStore ( reducers, {
  users: [{
    id: 22,
    fullname:   "Juan Perez",
    username:   "juanperez",
    email:  "juan@perez.io"}]
})
```

users container

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Table from '../../components/Table'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import Form from './form'
import axios from 'axios'
import config from '../../config/api'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { userListSuccess, addUser, saveUser, removeUser } from '../../actions/users'

class UsersContainer extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {

        var self = this;

        axios.get(config.path + '/users').then(response => {
            // DISPATCH USER_LIST_SUCCESS ACTION
            self.props.onUserListSuccess(response.data); 
        }).catch(function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        });;
    }

    render() {

        // HERE this.props.users IS EQUAL TO UNDEFINED
        console.log(this.props) 

        return (          

            <div>                      
                {
                  (typeof this.props.users !== 'undefined') && 
                      <Table data={this.props.users} />
                }

                { (this.props.users  || []).map( (u, i) => {
                    # DEBUGGING: THIS NEVER UPDATES WITH DATA
                    <span>{u.fullname}</span>
                } ) }                                    
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (store, ownProps) => {
    // THIS SHOWS THE TEST USER I HARCODED IN MY STORE. 
    console.log('test user', store); 
    return {
        users: store.users.list
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        onAddUser: (data) => { dispatch(addUser(data)) },
        onSaveUser: (data) => { dispatch(saveUser(data)) },
        onRemoveUser: (id) => { dispatch(removeUser(id)) },
        onUserListSuccess: (users) => { dispatch(userListSuccess(users)) }
    }
}

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(UsersContainer)
```

user actions

```
export function userListSuccess(users) {

    console.log('server-side users', users); // THIS DISPLAYS 21 USERS

    return {
        type: 'USER_LIST_SUCCESS',
        users
    }
}
...
```

Can you see where the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue is this block of code:

```
const mapStateToProps = (store, ownProps) => {
    // THIS SHOWS THE TEST USER I HARCODED IN MY STORE. 
    console.log('test user', store); 
    return {
        users: store.users.list
    }
}
```

`store.users` is an array of user objects based on your test data; `store.users.list` is `undefined` if that's the case because `Array` objects don't have property `"list"` by default.

Comment: Great, thanks, that solves the issue with my test user. Now I'll try to figure out how can I refresh the table with the data from axios.

Answer (score 0):

So, as Yiran Sheng said, my test user wasn't loading because I was missing a level in my test json. Fixing that I can see my initial user in the table.

Then, second issue was that the action dispatched by axios wasn't being reflected in a reducer. So i wrote this one:

```
case 'USER_LIST_SUCCESS':   
    let newState = Object.assign({}, state)       
    newState.list = action.response.data;
    return newState;
```

Still, my view woudn't refresh but that was a datatable issue. Now the data provided by store is right. Thanks.